# Laravel Crash when Uploading Large Files

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, file-upload

My Laravel application is crashing when I attempt to upload images to AWS S3 that are larger than ~6mb. I am using Laravel 5.6, php 7.2, and apache 2.4. This error is in a local dev environment.

I have the following `php.ini` settings:

- `max_execution_time = 300`
- `max_input_time = 300`
- `memory_limit = 256M`
- `post_max_size = 100M`
- `upload_max_filesize = 100M`

The is the only feedback I receive:

[image: Error in Chrome]

Firefox displays no error, just a blank screen. No errors get logged the JS console or to Laravel and Apache logs.

This is how I'm handling the image storage in the controller:

```
Image::create([
  'inductee_id' => $inductee->id,
  'path' => Storage::disk('s3')->putFile('images', $request->file('image_hero'), 'public'),
  'type' => 'raw',
  'image_credit' => request('image_hero_credit')
 ]);
```

This is working as intended when the overall file content size is below ~6mb. I have tried to use streams to upload the file, but received the same error using the following:

```
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');
$disk->put($targetFile, fopen($sourceFile, 'r+'));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your `/tmp`/ have enough space? How big is apache's request body?

Comment: The `/tmp` dir should have enough space and the request body is slightly larger than the image size (~6mb) as it only contains a few text field inputs.

Comment: Try explicitly setting tour LimitRequestBody size in your apache vhost

Comment: I set the limit request in vhosts to the following: `LimitRequestBody 0` (unlimited) with no luck.

Comment: What's on developers panel inside Network? Any requests with 500 response? What's in Laravel logs?